# Why Air Conditioner's voltage stabilizer shows bizarre approach to the desired voltage?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I've been observing my Air Conditioner's voltage stabilizer for many days  and I saw a bizarre pattern .Our country has standard lines of 220 VAC AT 50 Hz
Now since few days we've been experienceing voltage drops down occasionally to 170 and mostly stays at 190 to 195

Now the way voltage stabilizer approaches the 220 VAC seems bizarre to me:

*V_in  | V_stabilized*

**190   | 235**

**195   | 240**

200   | 210

215-219 | 220

Now you can see 190 approaches 235 but as we come close t desired Volatge(220) it is automatically stabilized to 219-220

Can you explain the working/reasoning behind this?

Are all the volatge-stabilizer/regulator made like so ?

^Any value or interval is omitted because I don't have data for them

Answer (score 3):

The voltage stabilizer mostly iikely uses an autotransformer to step the voltage up and down.

It automatically switched between the taps, so it uses one tap for stepping up from 190-195 to 235-240 (the same tap would step up from 178 to 220). Then, once the voltage gets high enough, it switches to another tap for stepping up from 200 to 210. Finally, nce the voltage gets high enough (215), the autotransformer is switched off and the input is passed trough straight.

This is cheaper than double conversion (convert AC to DC, then back to AC at the correct voltage) and is good enough if the load can tolerate slightly different voltages.

Line Interactive UPSs with AVR have the same voltage stabilization - straight, step down by 10% or step up by 10%. If stepping up or down results in the voltage still out of spec, the UPS switched to battery.